# Most recent rows with column from previous most recent rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have fetched all the rows with most recent rows for every orderID with this VIEW.But I also need another Column "**PreviousStatusID**" which will store the previous most recent row's StatusID.. Is it possible to implement ? Please Help.

The View :

```
    ALTER VIEW [dbo].[VW_PatientOrderByMaxTimeAddedProc]
AS
SELECT 
    t.ID, 
    t.ExamDate,
    t.ArrivalTime, 
    t.Activity, 
    t.PatientFirstName, 
    t.PatientMiddleName, 
    t.PatientLastName, 
    t.DOB,
    t.[Order],
    t.ActualExamTimeIn, 
    t.ActualExamTimeOut, 
    t.ActualScannerID, 
    t.ActualExamDate, 
    t.ActualCustomer, 
    t.ActualPatientFirstName, 
    t.ActualPatientLastName, 
    t.ActualDOB, 
    t.InsuranceCoID, 
    t.InsuranceID, 
    t.StartedInPreAuth,
    t.DateReceived, 
    t.TimeReceived, 
    FDGPatientOrder, 
    StatusID, 
    TimeAdded ,
    Notes, 
    cntID, 
    empID,
    Isotope,
    Weight,
    Diabetic,
    Indication,
    [Procedure],
    InjectionTime,
    PhysicianFirstName ,
    PhysicianText,
    IndicationDescription

 FROM           
  dbo.smsFDGPatientOrder t
  INNER JOIN
 dbo.smsFDGPatientOrderStatus ON t.ID = FDGPatientOrder
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT 
smsFDGPatientOrder.ID, 
MAX(TimeAdded) AS MAX_TIME
 FROM           
  dbo.smsFDGPatientOrder AS smsFDGPatientOrder 
  INNER JOIN
 dbo.smsFDGPatientOrderStatus ON smsFDGPatientOrder.ID = FDGPatientOrder
GROUP BY
smsFDGPatientOrder.ID
)
a ON  a.ID = t.ID and a.MAX_TIME = TimeAdded
```

Comment: please provide some test data in form of DML and add expected output

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL? In 2012+, you can use the LAG window function to make this not too bad.

```
SELECT  WindowedView.FDGPatientOrder
FROM    (
        SELECT  FDGPatientOrder,
                StatusId,
                TimeAdded,
                MAX(TimeAdded) OVER (PARTITION BY FDGPatientOrder) AS MostRecentTimeAdded,
                LAG(StatusId, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY FDGPatientOrder ORDER BY TimeAdded DESC) AS PrevStatusId
        FROM    PatientOrders
        ) WindowedView
WHERE   WindowedView.StatusId = 3
        AND WindowedView.PrevStatusId IN (4, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22)
        AND WindowedView.TimeAdded = WindowedView.MostRecentTimeAdded
```

Comment: looks like few modification is needed.

Comment: The whole thing is, or just the subquery? I'd expect the subquery to, that's using window functions to get inline aggregates. The full query I'd only expect that to happen if multiple rows have the exact same TimeAdded for the patient order.

Comment: Oh, oops, forgot to add partition by FDGPatientOrder. Also the ORDER BY in the MAX OVER isn't necessary. Edited, try now.